# tikzpicture: minor ticks are not displayed in the case of small data

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks

The code below is as expected, including the minor ticks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o] coordinates {
        (0.0, 1)
        (1.0, 0.5)
        (3,1e-6)
            };
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This code produces graph without minor ticks in y-directions (single change of the range)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o] coordinates {
        (0.0, 1)
        (1.0, 0.5)
        (3,1e-8)
            };
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

My question is, how to produce the same minor ticks in the case of small data?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough space for all the ticks. Enlarge the height a little bit:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  height=1.1*\axisdefaultheight% <- added
]
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o] coordinates {
        (0.0, 1)
        (1.0, 0.5)
        (3,1e-8)
            };
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```